# How to copy file from one directory to another using native code in Android?

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk

I want to copy file from on directory to another in my Native C program.
I tried using `system` function but it's not working.

`system("cp /mnt/test /mnt/test2"); // It's not working`

Also I want to know that even `system` function is supported in bionic libc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Android is Java, so what do you mean by Native C?

Comment: @WaynnLue I am using here Android NDK

Comment: Did you consider doing it on the java side?

Comment: No i want to do this on native code side (C side)

Answer (score 1):

**The Android shell does not have the cp command.** So if possible try `cat source_file > dest_file` .

Or just use this code,

```
FILE *from, *to;
  char ch;


  if(argc!=3) {
    printf("Usage: copy <source> <destination>\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* open source file */
  if((from = fopen("Source File", "rb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open source file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* open destination file */
  if((to = fopen("Destination File", "wb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open destination file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* copy the file */
  while(!feof(from)) {
    ch = fgetc(from);
    if(ferror(from)) {
      printf("Error reading source file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    if(!feof(from)) fputc(ch, to);
    if(ferror(to)) {
      printf("Error writing destination file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  if(fclose(from)==EOF) {
    printf("Error closing source file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(fclose(to)==EOF) {
    printf("Error closing destination file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
```

Also mentioned

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml** file..

**EDIT:**

You can use also `dd if=source_file of=dest_file`.

Redirection support is not needed.

Comment: Also I want to know that even system function is supported in bionic libc.

Comment: I also installed busy box for cp command. cp command is working on Android shell but i want to call this command from native C code

Comment: I used **execl()** command in c code for executing adb commands.

Comment: thanks for Reply But Here system("cp /mnt/test /mnt/test2"); is return some error code value also. So system function may be working. i also installed busy-box and i executed cp command directly on Shell then its working fine